# Media queries not work in firefox

Tags: css, media-queries

I have added following media query for my php project to hide an image when screen width is 1254px.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1255px ) {
    .visible-desktop {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

It works on Chrome correctly but it's not working on Firefox. Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Your media query is right and working perfectly in chrome and in firefox.

[As you can see on this JSFiddle...](https://jsfiddle.net/9fpz4dx4/1/)

I guess (since we dont have any more code) `.visible-desktop`'s display is being setted on some other position where you cant override it with your none. You could try using `!important`, which is not a beauty way, but can fix it in most times, but also not everytime.

```
display: none !important;
```

Comment: Have you tried if it will trigger when using !important?

Answer (score 1):

Your Code completely Worked.

**See Live Demo** [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/patelsumit5192/y5zeypc1/)

And Check This Url in `Firefox`. then Also work. i also try . See Image

[image]

**Snippet Example**

```css
 @media screen and (max-width: 1255px) {
            .visible-desktop{
                display: none;
            }
        }
```

```html
<div class="visible-desktop">
Hello visible-desktop Class 
</div>
```